Mutating an ES6 state variable in React seems to be synchronous
I'm seeing strange behavior that I can't explain. I have a state variable in React which is an ES6 Map:
const [errorMap, setErrorMap] = useState(new Map<string, string>([
  [ERROR_KEY_RECEIPT_NUMBER_STEP_1, ''],
  [ERROR_KEY_FORM_NUMBER_STEP_1, ''],
  ...

To mutate the map state variable, I need to actually create a new state variable, so I do it with the method handleErrorMapChange as follows:
const handleErrorMapChange = (id: string, value: any) => {
    setErrorMap(new Map<string, any>(errorMap.set(id, value)));
}

For some reason I see that unlike other state setters, which are async, if I call handleErrorMapChange my state variable errorMap changes immediately. When the debugger goes to the next line that state variable is immediately updated. But this is different from other state variables which are updated asynchronously, and when you go to the next line they're not ready.
handleErrorMapChange(ERROR_KEY_FORM_NUMBER_STEP_1, 'String');
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(errorMap)); // has the latest contents, sequentially
                                                          // no need to listen with an Effect

Is this just luck? Or is there a reason why it behaves like that?

Isn't errorMap.set(id, value) updating the existing map? If you want leave the original unchanged, you'll need to create the copy before mutating.

Yup that's the answer! Thanks, I missed that!

I'm not sure it's really async in general. It's a bit of a complex situation. It gets optimized according to the context within which its called.

Well you mustn't mutate the Map, you should set the state to a new Map!

@Max When is it not async in general?

FWIW, a plain object would be simpler to work with than a map here (seeing how your keys are strings) and almost certainly wouldn’t have tripped you (or anyone) up as easily.

@DaveNewton I don't know the details and the source code is quite complex to look through. But from what I understand react will optimize certain calls as tries to determine what's best. But here's an issue on react github repo that goes into it a bit https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527. Also the signature itself is not async in the sense that it's not a promise based async js function as is more common, where you await the return. I think the behavior is usually async but that's handled by react, where the render is async also. But I don't know if any guarantee of sync or async,

The older docs also say updates may be async, I haven't followed much react lately, maybe things have changed. https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous.  The newer docs https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate-caveats also mention how you can force sync updates.

If you mutate the state directly, React may not detect the change and fail to update the component properly.
To fix this, you should create a new Map instance instead of modifying the existing one. Here's how you can do it:
const handleErrorMapChange = (id: string, value: any) => {
    setErrorMap(prevErrorMap => {
        const newErrorMap = new Map(prevErrorMap); 
        newErrorMap.set(id, value); 
        return newErrorMap;
    });
};

